# XHTML bulk Validator for Windows?

Tags: xhtml, validation, bulk

I have several hundred (static - no includes or server-side parsing) HTML pages. I would like to validate the HTML (XHTML 1.0 Transitional), but the idea of plugging each of them individually into the W3C Validator - or even using a Firefox plug-in to open each one - fills me with dread.

Does anyone know of any (Windows) apps that can do bulk validation? The "Validate entire site" feature on http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator is the closest I've come, but that's limited to 100 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find something based on the [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with downloading the source and running it locally?

[Source code is here](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/source.html.en)

There is also [A Real Validator](http://arealvalidator.com/) for Windows, specially.

Answer (score 0):

We have written a tool that does this - upto 50,000 URLS in one go, our servers crunch all the data and e-mail you out a report:

http://www.cybercompare.net/web-hosting/bulk-html-validation/